# Can we install Agents of VS 2010 in Win 2012 R2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a Win 2012 R2 machine. It is going to be central testing server. Our developers use VS 2010, it agents requirement doesn't list Win 2012.

Now we are unsure if agents of VS 2010 can be installed. If installation is not possible is it possible to run test cases written in VS 2010 with Agents of VS 2013 or 2015?

Comment: Just try to install. I am sure it can be used.

Comment: Tx for the opinion. I guess yes our IT Admin is ok with doing it

Answer (score 0):

Just to close. Yes it can be installed and it is working.

And  I hate win 12 r 2 gui interface. Gives you no impression that you are working on server... Seems like a tab. IMO Server interface should some rigid attitude

Comment: It is typical now for system administrator to work with server remotely on tab. So it is comfortable to have tab-friendly interface

Comment: But why?? Ain't ppl tend to be careless when they are on tab?? Just my personal exp.